# Use client side function in QueryFilter

Tags: entity-framework-core

I used a List.Contains method **in a query filter** in Ef Core 2.2.1. Since the version 3.0, I have the message "query filter cannot be translated" because we have to manually inform EF that the query has to be excuted client side.

Is there a way to force this method to be executed client side ?

Precision : I have multiple query filter on some entities, most of them can be translated to SQL so I want to chose those who are executed client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the IList.Contains method instead List.Contains. If you use the List.Contains, you'll get the error. (watched the EF Core source code to understand that...)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AsEnumerable()` before the part of the query you want to run on the client.